# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest send fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I try to make an AJAX requestin Chrome using the following code:

```
var url = "http://" + document.domain + "/status_data.lua?resetsessiontimeout=false";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Using WireShark is see that send doesn't send anything... There is no `GET` emitted. 
But if I add an `&` at the end of the URL:

```
var url = "http://" + document.domain + "/status_data.lua?resetsessiontimeout=false&";
                                                                                   ^
```

then `send` will emit the `GET` request.

Is this expected?

Comment: Because I read it http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/04/ajax-readystate-is-4-but-statu.html

Comment: Chrome gives no error but the `xmlhttp.status` remains `0`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski no, nothing like that. It's just a page that should update some values every second...

Comment: Are you using this code on a subdomain different from the current domain (code runs under example.com and requests data from foo.example.com, or vice versa)?

Comment: @CBroe: No, it should be the same domain. Is there a possibility that Chrome tells me something like "Uhhh your trying to do a cross domain post"?

Comment: If that’s not the case, then I’m wondering why you’re going to the trouble of prefixing it with the protocol and host name anyway – why not just use the relative address, `"/status_data.lua?…"`?

Comment: @CBroe: Just to make sure that I don't have this problem

Comment: Have you tried with just the relative path?

Comment: @CBroe: Yes I did but no success...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess a couple of common errors people (and I) have made.

1. Did you create an instance of xmlhttp? In otherwords, do you have a line before your code above that has "var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();" (case sensitive)
2. Are you testing this through a file (like C:/test.html) or on a webserver (like Apache or jboss)? If you do the former, you'll get a Cross Point Origin error and doing the latter will fix it.
3. Are you sure the server code is not looking for additional variables after resetsessiontimeout? Because the '&' is used to delimit additional variables. Although I'm pretty sure it was unneeded to end a variable.

Like if I wanted to send an error string with that url. I can do
    resetsessiontimeout=false&errmsg=test

Comment: 1 - I'm doing `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();`, looks good

2 - I'm testing it using our proprietary WebServer

3 - The server doesn't even get the request, it is not even sent...

Comment: @Your reply to CBroe. Yes Chrome will scream if you try a cross domain post.